# How to update room database and How to get the insert status is working or completed?

Tags: android-room

The first:
I've got dataList from retrofit And insert Room Database.
I want to change dataList(Like insert a element). My Room Database can work because I used OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE. but when I delete dataList some elements, My Room Database can not delete elements.

```
Dao:
@Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertData(dataList : List<Data>) 

Entity:
@Entity
data class Data(
@PrimaryKey val Id : Long,
val Fl : String,
val FlMc : String,
val Dm : String,
val Mc : String,)

ViewModel:
fun insertData(dataList: List<Data>) = viewModelScope.launch {
    dataRepository.insertData(dataList)
}
//get data from server
fun getData():LiveData<List<Data>>
Activity:
dataViewModel.getData().observer(this){
    dataViewModel.insertData(it)
}
```

> How to resolve this situation except DELETE ALL THEN INSERT

The second:
I want to use a progressbar to indicate that I am inserting dataList

> How to get the insert status is working or completed

Comment: How to get the insert status is working or completed.  `suspend fun insertData(dataList : List<Data>): List<Long>` . Each element value will be either -1 (row not inserted) or a positive value that is the rowid of the inserted row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you issue is that you cannot delete because you are building a DataList item but don't know the primary key value as it's generated.

As you haven't shown the DataList entity then assuming it is like:-

```
@Entity
data class DataList(
    @PrimaryKey(autogenerate = true)
    val id: Long,
    val othercolumns: String
    ....
)
```

and if you change from `suspend fun insertData(dataList : List<Data>)` to **`suspend fun insertData(dataList : List<Data>): List<Long>`** (i.e. added the List as the result)

**Then you have the values of the id column in the result. In the case above the value is the value of the **id** column.**

If the @PrimaryKey is not an integer type e.g. a String then the long returned WILL NOT be the value of the primary key. It will be a special value known as the **rowid**.

In short using an integer with primary key makes the column an alias of the rowid. if not an integer primary key then it is not an alias BUT the rowid still exists.

You can still use the rowid to access a specific row as the rowid MUST be a unique value. e.g. (again assuming the above) you could have an @Query such as

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM the_datalist_table WHERE rowid=:rowid")
suspend fun getDataListById(rowid: Long)
```

- Only of use if you know the rowid though.

You could get rowid's say by using

```
@Query("SELECT rowid FROM the_datalist_table WHERE othercolumns LIKE :something")
 suspend fun getRowidOfSomeDataLists(something: String): List<Long>
```

- still not of great use as the selection criteria would also be able to provide a list of Datalists.

**Additional** re the comment:-

> How to use in viewModel or Activity?

As an example  you could do something like :-

```
fun insertData(dataList: List<Data>) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val insertedDataList: ArrayList<Data> = ArrayList()
    val insertedIdList = dataRepository.insertData(dataList)
    val notInsertedDataList: ArrayList<Data> = ArrayList()
    for(i in 0..insertedIdList.size) {
        if (insertedIdList[i] > 0) {
            insertedDataList.add(
                Data(
                    insertedIdList[i], //<<<<< sets the id as per the returned list of id's
                    dataList[i].Fl,
                    dataList[i].FlMc,
                    dataList[i].Dm,
                    dataList[i].Mc)
            )
        } else {
            notInsertedDataList.add(
                Data(
                    insertedIdList[i], //<<<<< sets the id as per the returned list of id's WILL BE -1 as not inserted
                    dataList[i].Fl,
                    dataList[i].FlMc,
                    dataList[i].Dm,
                    dataList[i].Mc
                )
            )
        }
    }
    val notInsertedCount = notInsertedDataList.size
    val insertedCount = insertedDataList.size
}
```

- So you have :-

  - **insertedDataList** an ArrayList of the successfully inserted Data's (id was not -1) with the id set accordingly.
  - **notInsertedDataList** an ArrayList of the Data's that were not inserted (id was -1) id will be set to -1.
  - **insertedCount** an Int with the number inserted successfully.
  - **notInsertedCount** and Int with the number not inserted correctly.

**DELETE ALL**

To delete **all** rows, unless you extract all rows you can't use the convenience `@Delete`, as this works on being provided the Object (Data) and selecting the row to delete according to the primary key (id column).

- The convenience methods @Delete, @Update, @Insert are written to generate the underlying SQL statement(s) bases upon the object (Entity) passed.

  - e.g. @Delete(data: Data) would generate the SQL `DELETE FROM data WHERE id=?`, where ? would be the value of the id field when actually run.

The simpler way to delete all columns is to use the `@Query` annotation (which handles SQL statements other than SELECT statements). So you could have.

```
@Query("DELETE FROM data")
fun deleteAllData()
```

- note that this does not the return the number of rows that have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I post my code in my question.  if I understant currently, the insert returns List<Long> each element is -1 when I insert complete.  How to use in viewModel or Activity?

Comment: @yansam you say *if I understant currently, the insert returns List<Long> each element is -1 when I insert complete.* **NO**, the List<Long> will either contain -1 (NOT INSERTED) or a number greater than 0 (INSERTED OK).  Edited the answer using the List<Long> as an example.

Comment: @yansam I believe that I have answered the question. If you are talking about *How to use in viewModel or Activity? * That would need to be another question, although I have edited the answer to show how you can process the result. Ongoing requests to basically write the application on your behalf is  beyond the scope of Stackoverflow. It is meant to be about providing answers to specific issues. I'd suggest that you do the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @MikeTT Sorry,  I apology . I means >How to resolve this situation except DELETE ALL THEN INSERT.  The No.1 question

Comment: @yansam thanks for clarifying. As per my first sentence in the answer I thought you were just having problems getting the list and wanted the list of id's. I have added how to delete all rows to the bottom of the question.